# struts2 checkboxlist to show aligned label

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I have a `List<Bill> bills`. `Bill` is a bean that has `id, amount, date, billDescription`.
I want to display a checkboxlist of `Bill` objects.  So I use:

```
<s:checkboxlist list="bills" name="selectedBills" 
    listKey="id" listValue="displayLabel"/>
```

my `Bill.getDisplayLabel()` prints out: "amount date billDescription"

```
40.00 5/1/2011 Electric Bill
1005.25 6/12/2012 Gas Bill
```

Problem is it is not aligned.  I want to customize my displayLabel so that the amounts align up, the dates align up, and the billDescription aligns up.  It should display as:

```
[ ]   40.00    5/1/2011    Electric Bill
[ ] 1005.26    6/12/2012   Gas Bill
```

with a checkbox in front of each.  Essentially I want to generate this code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedBills" value="9" id="selectedBills-1"/></td>
      <td style="text-align: right">40.00</td>
      <td>5/1/2011</td>
      <td>Electric Bill</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedBills" value="9" id="selectedBills-2"/></td>
      <td style="text-align: right">1005.26</td>
      <td>6/12/2012</td>
      <td>Gas Bill</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How do I do this?  The first column should have the checkbox, but the last 3 columns are 3 different parts of the label.  I tried putting in the `<td>` code inside my `Bill.getDisplayLabel()` but struts escapes it so that the actual `<td>` tags show up!

Any ideas will be appreciated.

updated: I already know how to vertically display the checkboxes by customizing the freemarker templates.

Comment: So you are actually want to split string? This is the very looong question for asking how to split string. :)

Comment: Why not to store this values in separate properties? Or just use `split` in FreeMarker template.

Comment: Test `<Div>` and `<P>` tag insead of `<table>`. i think it may works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [struts iterator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html)? I haven't tested this code properly. But I hope it could give you some idea :

```
<table>
  <s:iterator value="bills" var="bill">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedBills" value="${bill.id}" id="selectedBills-2"/></td>
    <td style="text-align: right">${bill.amount}</td>
    <td>${bill.date}</td>
    <td>${bill.description}/td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: This does solve the problem of my initial display rendering of the tabular data itself.   The problem comes into play if there is an error and I have to re-display the form with the original values (checkbox checks) preserved.  I'd have to set them myself in the JSP.  Thank goodness I don't have to worry about that now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using in the end:

```
<s:iterator value="bills" var="bill" status="rowstatus">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBills" value="${bill.id}" 
            id="selectedBills-${rowstatus.index}" />        
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right">${bill.amount}</td>
    <td >${bill.serviceDate}</td>
    <td>${bill.label}</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

and this works.  The problem with this is, if I have other fields on the JSP that fails validation, this will not work.  I'll have to put in additional jstl to make `checked="checked"` at the end of the `<input type="checkbox" ...>`